# TIMEOUT in Laravel

Tags: mysql, excel, laravel, timeout

So, i have to read a excel file in which each row contains some data that i want do write in my database. I pass the whole file to laravel, it reads the file and format it to a array and then i make a new insertion (or update) in my databse.
The thing is, the input excel file can contain thousands of rows and its taking a while to complete, giving a `timeout error` in some cases.
When i try to make this locally i use `set_time_limit(0);` function so timeout doesnt occur, and it works pretty wel. But in a remote server this function is disabled for security reasons and my code crashes because of a timeout.
Somebody can help in how to solve this problem ? Maybe another ideia in how to better solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice way to handle tasks that take a long time is by making use of so called [jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues).

You can make a job called `ImportExcel` and `dispatch` it when someone send you a file.

Take a good look at the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues), they have some great examples on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can take care of this using following steps :

**1. Take the csv file and store it temporarily in storage :**

You can store the large csv when user uploads. If it's something which is not uploaded from frontend, just make sure you have it saved to be processed in next step.

**2. Then dispatch a [job](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues) which can be queued :**

You can create a job which can handle this asynchronously. You can use [Supervisor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#supervisor-configuration) to manage queues and timeouts etc.

**3. Use package like [thephpleague](https://csv.thephpleague.com/) :**

Using this package(or similar), you can chunk the records or read one at a time. It is really really helpful to keep your memory usage under limit. Plus it has different options of methods available to read the data from files.

**4. Once file is processed, you can delete it from the temporary storage :**

Just some teardown cleanup activity.

Comment: I'm trying to do that, but i'm still having the same problem. I dont know what i did wrong, but laravel seems to still be blocking my application.

Comment: Whats max_execution_time defined in PHP?